# How to simplify this condition?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm learning about using `if-else` `else-if` conditions and I am wondering if there is anyway to simplify these statement below. Can I combine all of them into one statement?

```
if (a < 0) {
    a = 1;
}
if (b < 0) {
    b = 1;
}
if (c < 0) {
    c = 1;
}
```

Comment: As the variables are all independent from one another, you cannot combine the statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems not possible to combine all your mentioned if statements into one as `a`, `b`, `c` are all independent variables. However, to make your code more readable, you can take advantage of method.

e.g. Implement a method like this:

```
int processNegativeNumber(int num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
a = processNegativeNumber(a);
b = processNegativeNumber(b);
c = processNegativeNumber(c);
```

Comment: I would not call such a method `checkNumber`. First of all, the method performs an operation. Checknumber doesn't indicate such an action. Also, the value one is completely missing from the equation. Principle of least surprise is lost.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for your concern. `processNegativeNumber()` or `getValueForNegativeNumber()` => Do these naming make sense? Or, please feel free to modify the answer with the best practice in your opinion.

Comment: Yeah, the first one seems right, you can then document it returns 1. It is not fully descriptive, but that cannot really be avoided in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You could use ternary operator to save some chars :-)

```
a = a < 0 ? 1 : a;
b = b < 0 ? 1 : b;
c = c < 0 ? 1 : c;
```